# How to allow page to be displayed in a frame

Tags: php, html

When I share my page to stumbleupon, I get error on stumbleupon page:

```
Refused to display 'http://www.itsjournal.com/posts/148' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

So how is it possible to allow display page to frame? My current page header is:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Answer (score 0):

Configure your server or PHP (whichever is setting it) so it doesn't send the `X-Frame-Options` HTTP header.

> My current page header is …

That's part of your HTML document's `head`. You need to adjust the **HTTP** response header.